# Interactive floor plan like ticketmaster

Tags: reactjs

How to develop a interactive floor plan like ticket master, for example like [this](https://www1.ticketmaster.com/luke-combs-beer-never-broke-my-heart-tour/event/200055267ED295AB?f_PPL=true&ab=efeat5787v1)?

Comment: By trying it for yourself.

Comment: @Viira you have any idea about this.

Comment: And I want a million dollars.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest using SVG for drawing the shapes in the floor plan. You can attach event handlers to the SVG shapes to make them respond to click and other types of events. You can also specify classnames for the elements to style them, and change the styling e.g. when hovering. SVG integrates quite nicely with react and there are plenty of [tutorials](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2015/12/generating-svg-with-react/) on using them together.

The other option would be to use the HTML5 canvas to draw the shapes. That would also work, but in my opinion is not as suitable for this scenario, as you can't e.g. zoom graphics rendered with the canvas. You can still check out [this](https://www.sitepoint.com/canvas-vs-svg-choosing-the-right-tool-for-the-job/) comparison on SVG vs canvas for further info on their suitabilities for different needs.

You will also most likely need to build a backend that stores the floor plan data in a database and exposes it to the frontend. That is probably best done with a SQL database and a RESTful API that exposes it to the frontend.

To summarize: the frontend is best done with React (and maybe redux if the app is big) + SVG graphics, and the backend API with any tech you desire (e.g. node/express or python/django) + a SQL database (e.g. PostgreSQL).

Comment: Thanks @Kristian Salo for your suggestion but you know any library which I will use??

Comment: I just developed an interactive floor plan app for grocery stores with React and didn't find any suitable libraries for that use case. Sure, there are some floor plan libraries but most of them are unsuitable for this kind of need. I guess you'll need to do most of the development youself if the situation hasn't changed.

Comment: Thanks @Kristian Salo